# easyslider 1.7 failing after deployment with MVC3 ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, easyslider

I know its hard without a screenshot or a demo, but here it goes.

I have included an EasySlider1.7 widget in my home page. During my DEV runs from VS2010, the widget works fine, but when i deploy the site in my DEV SERVER on IIS 7, the images in the slider gets scattered throughout the web page.

Tried it out in Different Browsers, ensured that the JQuery file is linked properly. Debugging the script on IE gave me this error

> Object Doesn't support this property or method

in the below code

```
 $("#slider_home").easySlider({
                        /*continuous: true,*/
                        numeric: true,
                        nextId: "slider1next",
                        prevId: "slider1prev"
                    });
```

another error

> Object required

in the code

```
var controls = document.getElementById("controls");
controls.style.left = (984 + 237 - $("#controls").width()) / 2 + 5 + "px";
```

Thanks.